# Deserilize date keeping local time

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, json.net

Json dates are hard and the conversion seems to be escaping me. It seems to lose the time part inside the conversion.

I have the following Json Microsoft date being returned from an API. I know and can confirm the date is 5th May 2017 7am

[image]

However when deserializing the date using newtonsoft I can get it to retain it timezone information. I have tried all the various settings but cannot work this out.

[image]

My code to deserialize looks like this

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {
     DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.MicrosoftDateFormat,
     DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
     DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind
};

items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<UpcomingMeetingListDto>>(
                    responseContent, settings);
```

Sure it must be easy I just can fathom it out. I think it must be because the date format in the json has no associated TZ information. Maybe I need a custom date deserilizer to handle this case or set the culture.

I am using Newtonsoft.Json version 9.0.1

Comment: `1493704800000` is the 2nd of May 2017 in GMT. What timezone are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DateTime is deserialized correctly, but it is in GMT. To display the local time you should use ToLocalTime() method.

For example by adding a property to your UpcomingMeetingListDto.

```
public DateTime LocalMeetingDate => MeetingDate.ToLocalTime();
```

Try this [online epoch converter](https://www.epochconverter.com/), it shows you both local and gmt time.

Comment: thanks thought was going nuts assumed incorrectly is was 7am

Whats actually interesting is in the DB before I serialize it is 7am. Think the serialization is playing up :)  Using mvc 5,2 JsonResult. Gives me something to look at

Comment: Thanks fo helping me clear this up and sending me a better online epoch tool.  I ended up serialising to UTC using `SpecifyKind`
`